# Can't add object to NSMutableArray from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add objects to a NSMutableArray from another class and it won't work. It works perfectly for the other attribute.

I looked at similar questions but couldn't find a suitable answer.

The object iPack :

```
@interface IPack : NSObject

     @property float price;
     @property NSMutableArray *cocktails;

@end
```

In the class of my collection view :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.iPack = [[IPack alloc] init];
    self.iPack.cocktails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In the class of my cell :

```
self.collectionView.iPack.price = self.price //perfectly works

NSArray* cock = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:c1,c2,c3,c4,c5, nil];
[self.collectionView.iPack.cocktails addObjectsFromArray:cock]; //line won't work
```

Comment: Define `won't work`.

Comment: what do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Doesn't compile? Doesn't do what you expect?  have you checked that the view has actually been loaded, i.e. that the cocktails property is not still nil.

Comment: [self.iPack.cocktails addObjectsFromArray:cock];

Comment: It seems your `self.collectionView.iPack.cocktails` is `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown the `[IPack init]` method, but I strongly suspect you are not allocating the `cocktails` array.  Simply defining it as a property does not mean it's automatically allocated:

```
@implementation IPack

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _price = 0.0f;
        _cocktails = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**EDIT**

I've just seen this line in your question:

```
self.iPack.cocktails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Which would suggest my answer is wrong (despite it being the better way of doing the same thing). Sorry about that; I cannot see why your code doesn't work.  Are you sure you are checking correctly?

Comment: Yes, I am checking through a breakpoint... It is quite an annoying problem and I can't find another solution :/

Answer (score 0):

try this,

in `IPack` class add a method

```
@interface IPack : NSObject

     @property float price;
     @property NSMutableArray *cocktails;
     - (instancetype)initWithPrice:(float)price cocktails:(NSMutableArray *)cocktails;
@end
```

and in implementation

```
@implementtion IPack

- (instancetype)initWithPrice:(float)price cocktails:(NSMutableArray *)cocktails {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.price = price;
        self.cocktails = cocktails;
    }
}

@end
```

In the class of my collection view :

remove alloc init in `viewDidLoad`
that is remove the following lines

```
self.iPack = [[IPack alloc] init];
self.iPack.cocktails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In the class of my cell :

```
NSArray* cock = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:c1,c2,c3,c4,c5, nil];
IPack *ipack = [[IPack alloc] initWithPrice:self.price cocktails:[NSMutableArray arrayArray:cock]];
self.collectionView.iPack = ipack;
```